Are there free offline PC tools converting azw3/epub to mobi? (Except Calibre and Kindlepreview)
Are there free offline PC tools converting azw3/epub to mobi? (Except Calibre and Kindlepreview) The online free converts have so many limitations such as file size and file count.

Why not Calibre?
